# get Math.round to round up to next minute even if over by a second

Tags: javascript, math, xhtml, rounding

Related to my previous question [javascript math.round and math.floor work fine in IE and Opera but not Chrome, Safari or Firefox. Getting NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866752/javascript-math-round-and-math-floor-work-fine-in-ie-and-opera-but-not-chrome-s)

I have updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/8VmPm/

The reason behind this script may seem a little cloudy so I'll try to explain. CDRs (Call detail records) from a certain network operator come in seconds for voice records and bytes for data records. I'm writing a "calculator" to convert seconds to minutes and bytes to megabytes.

I also took it a step further and added some example plans in there to check for overage.

My problem (which is simply cosmetic, but I am OCD like that) is in the first calculation `(Math.round(minusage / 60))` (lines 22 and 23 in fiddle). I need it to round up to the next minute even if the value entered in the **Usage Used** field is over by 1 second.

Example:

1. In the Minute **Which Plan?** dropdown, pick *Plan A* (500 Minutes)
2. In the **Usage Used** field, enter in *30001* (which is 500 minutes and 1 second)
3. Click the **Calculate** button

Results in the **Usage Summary** field will be:

*500 minutes used. -1 of 500 minutes remaining*

Currently, it will not say, "*501 minutes used*" until the value entered in **Usage Used** field is 30030 or greater (for Plan A)

I **need** it to go to the next minute up even if over by 1 second (otherwise it'll confuse the non-techies who will be using it)

Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `Math.ceil(...)`. It is a JavaScript method for rounding up to the nearest integer. Here is a link to the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil).

Comment: No problem - It's what I'm here for :)